# jQuery class selector vs cached element + find

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

I have a situation where I'm wondering what the best approach is performance-wise.

I have a class name, let's call it **.class-test**.
I also have a cached element, **$body**.

I can either retrieve the .class-test element by:

```
$('.class-test')
```

or by

```
$body.find('.class-test')
```

In a worst-case scenario, does one of these approaches win out over the other? Also, if someone could describe what is being done under the hood by the second approach that would be great (i.e. I know that .find defers to Sizzle, but if the element is cached does it already have a tree of its DOM elements stored, then it only needs to traverse that sub-tree to find the class? or is that tree only built as-needed?).

Comment: Try it here http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Unless you're looking up thousands of elements, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said worst-case. Since most jQuery performance metrics rely on using thousands of elements. I'd also be interested to know what's going on under the hood of the second approach.

Comment: Most likely it's a foreach looping over each selected element, and for each selected element, it's doing `element.getElementsByClassName("class-test")` then joining them all as one unique collection of elements. In your example, the difference will be very small, however in a larger example where the cached element is a more precise element than the body, the performance difference might be larger. There is no general rule for this. Test it on a case-by-case basis and in multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is how many times you dip in the DOM pool so to speak. In the first query, jQuery will search from within the document( top level ) and travel down in to the DOM tree checking every level till it gets to the very end and then returns all of the matching elements.

In the second option, you specify the starting point, so instead of starting at the very top and working its way down you are starting at the body element. In this particular case you are only going one level lower but here is the real plus, since you have the body cached, jquery doesn't have to find that it can just reference the cached element.

When you get deeper into the DOM tree this can be a big time saver. You can save 10s to 100s of level checks. And although you wont notice this much for small sites, one day you may be working with enterprise level code bases where these performance gains will be very beneficial to you.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought and why I always try to cache my elements and use find.

I guess what I really should have asked was does caching an element mean that we are storing it's DOM structure in memory, which I guess is what happens, so when I reference that cached element with a 'find' method we don't have to initialize that cached element's DOM tree before executing the 'find'.

Comment: and just to clarify jquery uses the default querySelector and querySelectorAll in modern browsers, and relies on Sizzle (their selector engine) for older browsers

Comment: Doesn't 'find' specifically defer to Sizzle.find?

Comment: right, but sizzle behind the scenes will use el.querySelectorAll() if in a modern browser

Comment: so to save a bit of time and the check by sizzle you could do $( el.querySelectorAll('.test-class')) and it would be just a tiny bit faster way to get a jquery wrapped set of elements